# How much time is between Phineas and Ferb and Milo Murphy's Law?

Tags: continuity, time, phineas-and-ferb, milo-murphys-law

*Phineas and Ferb* aired from 2007-2015. *Milo Murphey's Law* first aired in 2016, according to Wikipedia there may or may not be another season at some point in the future. These 2 shows are crossovers, they take place in the same universe. MML seemingly takes place shortly after P&F, but I'd like to have a more precise time frame. Here's what I have so far:

- P&F takes place during the Summer
- At the end of P&F, Dr. Doofensmirtz becomes a good guy
- From the episode *Doof 101* that he becomes a teacher once the school year starts
- In MML he is not evil nor a teacher, this show takes place during the school year as characters are at school at several points
- Most likely Dr. Doofernsmirtz wouldn't have left teaching in the middle of a semester so it's likely not during the Fall directly after the show
- When various children from P&F appear in MML they are seemingly the same age so apparently it's not long after the conclusion of that show

Does anyone have more pinpoint info on this?